# Why does $\text{arctanh}(2^{-k})$ approach powers of $2$?

Tags: calculus, limits, asymptotics, hyperbolic-functions

This is from a piece of verilog code I generated for $\text{arctanh}(2^{-k})$:

```
localparam bit [31:0][47:0] arctanhTable = {
        48'b100011001001111101010011110101010110100000011000,
        48'b010000010110001010111011111010100000010001010001,
        48'b001000000010101100010010001110010011110101011101,
        48'b000100000000010101011000100010101101001101110101,
        48'b000010000000000010101010110001000100100011010111,
        48'b000001000000000000010101010101100010001000101011,
        48'b000000100000000000000010101010101011000100010001,
        48'b000000010000000000000000010101010101010110001000,
        48'b000000001000000000000000000010101010101010101100,
        48'b000000000100000000000000000000010101010101010101,
        48'b000000000010000000000000000000000010101010101010,
        48'b000000000001000000000000000000000000010101010101,
        48'b000000000000100000000000000000000000000010101010,
        48'b000000000000010000000000000000000000000000010101,
        48'b000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000010,
        48'b000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000,
        48'b000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000,
        48'b000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000,
        48'b000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000,
        48'b000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000,
        48'b000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000,
        48'b000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000,
        48'b000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000,
        48'b000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000,
        48'b000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000,
        48'b000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000,
        48'b000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000,
        48'b000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000,
        48'b000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000,
        48'b000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000,
        48'b000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000
    };
```

The $\text{arctanh}(2^{-k})$ values start converging to successive powers of $2$.  It's apparent that the number of zeroes between the first $1$ and the second $1$ keeps increasing, so the form $\text{arctanh}(2^{-k}) = 2^{-1} + q(k)$ for values of $q(k)$ decreasing much more quickly than values of $2^{-k}$.  Wolfram Alpha tells me $q(k) = -2^{-k} - \dfrac{\ln(1-2^{-k}) + \ln(1+2^{-k})}{2}$

Why does this divergence happen?  I don't think I can leverage this to cheaply calculate $\text{arctanh}$, although it does give me an interesting way to compress the table by storing a floating-point $q(k)$, not that that's actually useful either.

Comment: Do you think people here are going to know how t9 read that code? $\tanh x - x\to 0$ as $x\to 0,$ so the same is true near the inverse.

Comment: Yes.  Fixed that now.

Comment: See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HEfHFsfGXjs for 2 really cool explanations by 3 blue 1 brown.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We know that

$$ \DeclareMathOperator{\arctanh}{artanh}
   \arctanh(x) = \frac12\left(\log(1 + x) - \log(1 - x)\right). \tag1$$

The Taylor series for $\log(1+x)$ centered at $x=0$ is
$$ \log(1 + x) = x - \frac12 x^2 + r_1(x) $$
where $r_1(x)$ is $\mathcal O(x^3)$ as $x \to 0$.
Similarly, the Taylor series for $\log(1 - x)$ centered at $x=0$ is
$$ \log(1 - x) = -x - \frac12 x^2 - r_2(x) $$
where $r_2(x)$ is $\mathcal O(x^3)$ as $x \to 0$.

Substituting these two Taylor series into Equation $(1)$ gives

\begin{align}
 \arctanh(x)
&= \frac12\left(\left(x - \frac12 x^2 + r_1(x)\right)
                 - \left(-x - \frac12 x^2 + r_2(x)\right)\right) \\
&= x + r_1(x) + r_2(x) \\
&\subseteq x + \mathcal O(x^3), \quad x \to 0. \\
\end{align}

Let $x = 2^{-k}$ for a positive integer $k$ and you have
$$ \arctanh(2^{-k}) \subseteq 2^{-k} + \mathcal O(2^{-3k}), \quad k \to \infty. $$

In other words, $q(k)$ is a function of order $2^{-3k}.$
So its first non-zero digit is about three times as many places to the right as the $1$ digit of $2^{-k}$, leaving about $2k$ zeros between the digits.

For example, consider the following two rows of your table.

```
        48'b000000000100000000000000000000010101010101010101,
        48'b000000000010000000000000000000000010101010101010,
```

The first of these two rows has nine zeros followed by a $1$,
which is the $2^{-k}$ digit of $\arctanh(2^{-k})$,
then we have $21$ zeros followed by some non-zero digits;
if this is the row for $k = 10$ then indeed we have about $2k$ zeros
($2k+1$ to be exact) between the non-zero digits.
In the next row the $2^{-k}$ digit has moved one place to the right,
but the rest of the digits have moved three places, adding two zeros to the gap between non-zero digits.
And we will just keep on adding two more zeros on every row,
which is a simple consequence of the fact that $q(k)$ is of order
$2^{-3k},$ or in other words, when $k$ is large,
$q(k)$ is approximately $\lambda 2^{-3k}$ for some constant $\lambda$.

Comment: It might be apt to point out that this $\mathcal O(x^3)$ behavior of $q$ that you describe in the final paragraph is readily visible in the table in the question post: The remainder part moves three bits to the right for each row down while the main part moves only one bit to the right.

Comment: @Arthur Thanks for the idea!

Comment: Nice.  I didn't know big-O notation was used outside of algorithm complexity…didn't think of it that way.

Comment: Indeed big-O notation is not limited to algorithm complexity, but in this application we need to remember that it is big-O for **small** numbers, not for large numbers. A function that is $\mathcal O(x^3)$ for small $x$ might not be $\mathcal O(x^3)$ for large $x,$ and vice versa. Just a word to the wise so you aren't tripped up by this at some future time!

Comment: I don't quite like your vague remark on Big-O. Why don't you just tell @JohnMoser clearly that you are using Big-O for real $x → 0$, whereas CS tends to use Big-O for natural $n → ∞$? In fact, if people always explicitly state the limiting condition in their use of Big-O, we won't even be seeing this **very frequent** confusion...

Comment: @JohnMoser: For instance, $O(x) ⊆ O(x^2)$ as $x → ∞$, but $O(x^2) ⊆ O(x)$ as $x → 0$, and in each case the containment does not reverse.

Comment: @user21820 I don't recall seeing "as $x \to \infty$" in this context but I like the idea and have applied it in the answer--I hope as you intended. I've also attempted to use $\subseteq$ correctly instead of the traditional but dubious $=$. As for my comment, aside from the fact that I can't edit it, "small $x$" vs. "large $x$" is how I think about it. Interestingly, with $x=2^{-k},$ small $x$ is large $k.$

Comment: Indeed, your latest edit is excellent! Yes of course intuitively we think in terms of small and large, and so when talking about it to students it's perfectly fine to use these intuitions. My only intention is as you understood, namely that for written precision we can use just a few more words to remove any ambiguity. For some actual usages of "as $n → ∞$", you can see [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Remarks). =)

Comment: And we can also capture your last observation symbolically: Take $x = 2^{-k}$. As $k → ∞$, we have $2^k → ∞$ and hence $x → 0$. Since $\text{atanh}(x) ∈ x+O(x^3)$ as $x → 0$, we get $\text{atanh}(2^{-k}) ∈ 2^{-k}+O(2^{-3k})$ as $k → ∞$.

Answer (score 9):

The reason that $\lim_{i\to\infty}\frac{\operatorname{arctanh}(2^{-i})}{2^{-i}}=1$ is that $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\operatorname{arctanh}(h)}{h}=1$. This is in turn true because $\operatorname{arctanh}(0)=0$ so this is really the expression $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\operatorname{arctanh}(h)-\operatorname{arctanh}(0)}{h-0}=\frac{d(\operatorname{arctanh})}{dx}(0)=1$.

You will get the same behaviour with any other function which, like $\operatorname{arctanh}$, at $x=0$ has the value equal to $0$, and the value of the first derivative equal to $1$.

The reason we see a big "gap" of zeros after the first "one" (i.e. the values are *very* close to $2^{-i}$) is that the *second derivative* has the value $0$, i.e. $\frac{d^2(\operatorname{arctanh})}{dx^2}(0)=0$ This then in turn means that the function is well approximated by its Taylor polynomial of $2$nd degree, which ends up being $\frac{1}{1!}\cdot x+\frac{0}{2!}\cdot x^2=x$, i.e. $\operatorname{arctanh}(x)=x+O(x^3)$ and so the order of magnitude of the error term is therefore close to $2^{-3i}$. Cf. [Wolfram Alpha McLaurin expansion for $\operatorname{arctanh}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=mclaurin%20series&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22TaylorSeries%22%2C%20%22taylorFunction%22%7D%20-%3E%22arctanh%28x%29%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22TaylorSeries%22%2C%20%22taylorPoint%22%7D%20-%3E%220%22).

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense.  I guess that also explains where the $K$ value comes from in CORDIC functions, and why the results are inaccurate if you don't truncate the look-up table to the eventual number of digits being generated.